# Trying to automate opening a TFS workitem directly in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Having trouble figuring out how to open a visual studio workitem directly in visual studio, without resorting to the web interface.

Right now, I have an autohotkey script that parses the # and just executes a shortcut to GO TO WORKITEM > Enters number and then proceeds. However, I'd really like to open the workitem directly via command line or URI.

I've tried syntax such as [image: test syntax]
However, this gives me an error like this: 
[image]

I've validated the full default collection name we use with our TFS admin. In addition, before it gives me the error, it opens a brand new instance of VS2013, instead of opening in the existing instance.

I hope someone could shed light on a way to open a workitem directly via command line/URI, etc. Ideally, I want to embed the URI/LINK in Onenote 2013 so I can click on the link and go straight to the workitem in Visual studio.

Ideally, the solution needs to be outside an extension (as previous questions have focused on API/extension actions doing this). I am hoping there is some way to correctly pass the command line argument, or URI and open the workitem, without requiring an extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a tfs work item inside Visual Studio 2010 inside a Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864696/how-to-open-a-tfs-work-item-inside-visual-studio-2010-inside-a-extension)

Comment: @DaveShaw thanks! I definitely looked at that post first. The problem is that post focuses specifically "inside extension". I'm trying avoid developing an extension or anything more complex. I was hoping there is a better way to trigger this action based on command line, URI, or some other method. Please don't close this as a dup as the scope is different. thanks!

Comment: I can't retract my vote, but I don't think anyone else will vote to close now. I tried a number of command lines last night and managed to get a tab with a WI ID but no content.

Comment: I have not had luck either. Seems like with some much extensibility there would be a way!

Comment: If your goal is to show a work item, use the web interface URL, e.g.  _http://MyServer:8080/tfs/MyCollection/MyProject/_workitems/edit/12345

Comment: But that would open in web, I'm trying to open directly in open visual studio ide

Comment: Here is a link that should answer your question.
[How do open an existing work item in Visual Studio from an outside process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630388/how-do-open-an-existing-work-item-in-visual-studio-from-an-outside-process)

Answer (score 1):

From the command line (DOS), use START + the path...
`START vstfs:///WorkItemTracking/WorkItem/999999?url=http://MY.SERVER:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`

You can create a batch file and pass in the work item number to make it easier.

Comment: This successfully opened in a new visual studio instance for 2017. That's pretty awesome! However, it ignored the existing visual studio instance, which I would have liked it open in directly without having a brand new VS startup. Not sure if anyway to get that to happen

Comment: You can also use shellexecute().  See that answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630388/how-do-open-an-existing-work-item-in-visual-studio-from-an-outside-process.